# What does a node hour mean in Vertex AI and how do I estimate how many I'll need for a job?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Much of Vertex AI's [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/pricing) is calculated per node hour. What is a node hour and how do I go about estimating how many I'll need for a given job?

Answer (score -1):

A node hour represents the time a virtual machine spends running your prediction job or waiting in a ready state to handle prediction or explanation requests. The cost of one node running for one hour is a node hour.

The price of a node hour varies across regions and by operation.

You can consume node hours in fractional increments. For example, one node running for 30 minutes costs 0.5 node hours.

There are tables in the [pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/pricing) that can help you estimate your costs, and you can use the [Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/).

You can also use [Billing Reports](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports#filtering_and_grouping) to monitor your usage.

Comment: The main question here is - how do I estimate how many node hours do I need? This answer doesn't help.